# Calling a function in a different class, using its classes variables

Tags: python

I want to add UDIMS to the a mesh, which is created in class A.

```
import bpy

class A(Operator):
    ...
    #stuff happens
    ...
    B.add_udim()


class B(Operator):
    bl_label = "Very cool label"
    bl_idname = "wm.add_udim"

    edge_lenx : bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "UDIM-Count, X:", default = 1, min = 1, max = 10)
    edge_leny : bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "UDIM-Count, Y:", default = 1, min = 1)


    
    @classmethod
    def add_udim(self):
        tile_nr = None
        udim_tex = bpy.data.images.new(name="UDIM Texture", width=1024, height=1024, tiled=True)
        for ix in range(self.edge_lenx):

            for iy in range(self.edge_leny):
                
                tile_nr = 1001 + iy*10 + ix
                udim_tex.tiles.new(tile_number=tile_nr)
```

I hope this shows what I am trying to do.
This however produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'edge_lenx'
```

Which I am very confused by, since the execute function in class B already used these variables.

If you find any typo in the code itself, it happened while copying it into here, the code runs fine, until the line, where the add_udim function wants to use the edge_length-variables.

Comment: You can't use operators like that. `edge_lenx` is a class annotation, and it is used by the Blender API to dynamically add this property to the *instance* of the class that's generated from the class definition. The class `B` doesn't actually know what `edge_lenx` is and you can't access it from outside the class. You may want to define these properties globally ,eg `bpy.types.Scene.edge_lenx = bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "UDIM-Count, X:", default = 1, min = 1, max = 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution could be putting all properties into a PropertyGroup and access them via context in the execute method using a separate function created:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator as Operator
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup as PropertyGroup

#make your method a separate function
def add_udim(context):
    my_props = context.scene.my_props
    #instead of using self. use my_props. class
    
    tile_nr = None
    udim_tex = bpy.data.images.new(name="UDIM Texture", width=1024, height=1024, tiled=True)
for ix in range(my_props.edge_lenx):

    for iy in range(my_props.edge_leny):
        
        tile_nr = 1001 + iy*10 + ix
        udim_tex.tiles.new(tile_number=tile_nr)


class A(Operator):
    #your stuff here
    
    def execute(self, context): #add execute to access context and run the function
    add_udim(context)


class B(Operator):
    #your stuff here


#add property group for all your properties
class Props(PropertyGroup):
    edge_lenx : bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "UDIM-Count, X:", default = 1, min = 1, max = 10)
    edge_leny : bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "UDIM-Count, Y:", default = 1, min = 1)

#register and assign the property group to the PointerProperty
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(A)
    bpy.utils.register_class(B)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Props)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.my_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = Props)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(A)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(B)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Props)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_props

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1):

This construction is the [annotate](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/):

```
edge_lenx : bpy.props.IntProperty()
```

And this is an equivalent of:

```
edge_lenx = None # bpy.props.IntProperty()
```

So you have to initialize these values before use them. It can be like this:

```
edge_lenx : bpy.props.IntProperty() = 1
```

But I see, that it is not that you want. Then Blender runs operator, it creates an instance of the class, fill annotations with real properties and after the operator has finished, this instance is no longer accessible. So as Gorgious sad, you can save these properties somewhere globally to get access later.